# Which one is better? October Treat vs Shroom Grace?

Tags: axie-infinity

[image]

People says October Treat. It's an S card. But Shroom's Grace heals for 120 and adds 40 shield. Seems like a much better bargain.

Comment: It's probably situational. More shield it's always useful, but sometimes you need the healing. (I'm speculating, never played this before)

Answer (score 1):

I asked in an Axie Infinity group.

Shroom's Grace heals. That's cool.

However, enemies anticipate that. So enemies will one round kill the plant if they see the plant can heal.

October Treat however, raise shield. Yes it's only 110. However it makes plants harder to kill because the shield show up at the beginning of the round.

The healing of Shroom's Grace, however, happens often after the plant is death and hence useless.

Also October Treat draw card if shield doesn't break. This is something I ignored. However, people actually like the card draw. This makes October Treat a stable card.